# My Wordpress plugin needs Facebook API access. Should each user create a Facebook app for access?

Tags: php, wordpress, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

The title pretty much says it all. I'm writing a Wordpress plugin that needs Facebook API access. In order to get Facebook API access, it is neccessary to create a Facebook "App".

I plan to release this plugin to the public. Would it be best practice for me to use a single Facebook app that *I have created* as the access point for *everyone's* API requests (that is, everyone who uses the plugin)? Or should each person who uses the plugin create their own Facebook App for their own API access?

I'm just looking for "best practice" here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what the plugin is about, but in general it´s a good idea to let users create their own App. The user can just enter his App ID and App Secret in the plugin settings. An important benefit is that you are not responsible for it if someone uses your App for something malicious. Also, you need to use the correct URL settings if you want to implement user login, so one App for everyone would not even work in some cases.

TL;DR: It depends on the plugin, in general let users create their own App.

Comment: Sweet, okay. Good to know. I'm thinking this goes for other social media apps as well (Twitter, Instagram, etc.)?

Comment: yes, especially because there are api call limits for calls without a user token and stuff...per app.